# Trigger action in form submit javascript html

Tags: javascript, html, regex, forms, validation

I am trying to validate the fields in the form and pull up a different html file when the user clicks the submit button if there's no error in field validation.

1. However, the validators don't seem to work. I want the Event Name and Location fields to alphanumeric characters and spaces, but it seems to take other values as well.
2. Putting **onClick="self.location='successPage.html'"** inside the submit button does not seem to validate the fields either. I want it to move to the successPage.html file if all fields in the form are successfully validated.

I don't want to use jQuery.

Here is my code:

```html
<form action="" >
  <p>
   <label>
     Day of the week:<br>
      <select name="days">
     <option value="mon">Monday</option>
     <option value="tue">Tuesday</option>
     <option value="wed">Wednesday</option>
     <option value="thu">Thursday</option>
     <option value="fri">Friday</option>
     </select><br>
   </label>
   <label>
     Start Time:<br>
     <input id="appt1" type="time" name="appt1" min="9:00" max="18:00" required /><br>
   </label>
   <label>
     End Time:<br>
     <input id="appt2" type="time" name="appt2" min="9:00" max="18:00" required /><br>
   </label>
   <label>
     Event Name:<br>
     <input id="ename" type="text" name="ename"  required /><br>
   </label>
   <label>
     Location:<br>
     <input id="loc" type="text" name="location" required /><br><!--pattern="[A-Za-z0-9\s]"-->
   </label>
   <label>
     Enter URL for the pictture:<br>
     <input id="urlpic" type="text" name="urlname" />
   </label>
   <br><br>
   
   <input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
   <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /><!--onClick="self.location='successPage.html'"-->
   <!-- <input type=button value="Submit" onClick="self.location='successPage.html'"> -->
  </p>
  </form>
    <script>
  function chkName() {
   var myName = documnet.getElementById("ename");
   var pos = myName.value.search( /^[A-Za-z0-9\s]/);
   if (pos != 0) {
    alert("Please check your input (" + myName + ") again");
    return false;
   } else
    return true;
  }
  
  function chkLoc() {
   var myLoc = documnet.getElementById("loc");
   var pos = myLoc.value.search( /^[A-Za-z0-9\s]/);
   if (pos != 0) {
    alert("Please check your input (" + myLoc + ") again");
    return false;
   } else
    return true;
  }
  
  document.getElementById("ename").onchange = chkName;
  document.getElementById("loc").onchange = chkLoc;
  
  </script>
```

Comment: `self.location`? Do you have some custom environment or do you mean `window.location`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="." method="POST" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

the form element will be passed into the validate function when the user submits, return false to not submit the form, and true to submit it.

```
<script>
    function validate(form) {
        console.log(form); // log element to console on submit
        return false; // replace with true if input is good to be submitted
    }
</script>
```